# Как сделать шапку на всю ширину?

Tags: html, css

[image]

На ширине экрана 480px  background-image у шапки  сжимается и  справа вылезает общий фон,как исправить

```css
/* Общие стили */
* 
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

article, figure, footer, header, nav, section 
{
  display: block;
}

ul 
{
  list-style: none;
}     
    
a 
{
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Шапка */
header 
{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

/* Меню*/
.logo 
{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 25px;
}    
    
.spisok 
{
  display: block;
  float: right;   
  margin-top: 70px;
}  
    
.menu_1
{
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu_2
{
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu_3
{
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}   
    
a:hover 
{
  color: #ffffff; /* Цвет ссылки при наведении на нее курсора мыши */  
  text-decoration: underline; /* Добавляем подчеркивание */
}

ul.spisok li 
{
  display: inline;
}

.pp
{
  text-align: right;
}    
    
.menu 
{
  float: right;
}

.menu li 
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu a 
{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  color: darkcyan;
  padding: 25px;
}   
    
.menu a:hover 
{
   color: #fff;
   background-color: darkcyan;
}    
    
/* Основное содержимое */
.container 
{
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;   
}

@media (min-width: 480px )and (max-width:768px) {
* {font-size: 40px;} 
 /* Ширину класса container делаем резиновой */
     
header {
  width: 100%;
}       
    
.container 
{
  max-width: 90%;
}
    
/* Расположение блоков в footer делаем в одну колонку */
.col-three 
{
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
} 

.image
{
  float: none;
}

.text_image
{
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<header>   
  <nav class="container"> 
    
    <a>
      <figure class="logo">
        <img width="100" height="100" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Telegram_Messenger.png" >
      </figure>
    </a>
    
    <ul class="spisok"> <!-- Ссылки на пункты меню -->
      <li class="menu_1"><a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram">История Telegram </a></li> <!-- Ссылка 1 -->
      <li class="menu_2"><a href="https://web.telegram.org/#/login">Web-Версия Telegram</a></li> <!-- Ссылка 2 и т.д. -->
      <li class="menu_3"><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.messenger&hl=ru&gl=US">Telegram для телефона</a></li>
    </ul>
    
  </nav> 
</header>
```

Comment: светлый фон= background-image у шапки, фиолетовый фон  задан всему body

Comment: С увеличением ширины экрана шапка увеличивается в ширину и всё хорошо,с уменьшением же уходит влево

Comment: Лучше рабочий код здесь покажите, он же простой совсем судя по картинке.

Comment: обычный градиент вроде, зачем тут image ? а так background-size видимо указать

Comment: ну так у вас там .container: max-width: 90%;

Answer (score 0):

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
}
```